# Using PHP 8.1.0 with Apache

Tags: php, apache, backend

I'm new to this. I'm using Thread Safety enabled PHP 8.1.0 and Apache 2.4, they're on the same x64 architecture. I found that Apache wasn't finding the files in these lines

```
PHPIniDir D:\drp76933\php
LoadModule php8_module D:\drp76933\php\php8apache2_4.dll
```

because they had previously led to the wrong directory by default and had directed to the php 7.4.22 version of that dll file. It also used `php7_module` instead.

I have a new error message. when I try to test apache with `httpd -t`

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 540 of D:/drp76933/Apache/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `php8_module' in file D:/drp76933/php/php8apache2_4.dll: No error
```

It seems like `php8_module` doesn't work. Can I use php 8, and if so, what do I change for this to work? If not, do I have to downgrade? It isn't a big deal, I just feel it would be helpful to learn this info for future reference (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out I simply have to change `php7_module` or `php8_module` with just `php_module` and get rid of the double quotation marks on the directory, worked just fine with PHP 8 that way.